# Why am I unable to set minSdkVersion

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, ant, command-line

I can't work out any reason at all why I am seemingly unable to set a minSdkVersion for my application from the manifest. I am compiling from the terminal using Ubuntu OS - simply using> ant debug

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="self.redway.menubardemo"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk 
        minSdkVersion="11"
        targetSdkVersion="20"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MenuBarActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and yet when I compile the output in the terminal says:

[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4W
[gettarget] API level:        20
[gettarget] WARNING: No minSdkVersion value set. Application will install on all Android versions.
     [echo] ----------

And although it runs the application is not giving me the action bar or the holo theme I expect when my min target is set at 11.

Is there something I need to do to the build path or something tricky. There is literally nothing to be found on the subject on here or google generally. Totally stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `android` namespace prefix with your attributes. That is, `android:minSdkVersion` instead of default `minSdkVersion`.

The same problem is there with `targetSdkVersion`, too.

Comment: Omg how silly of me. Thanks so much for spotting it.

Answer (score 2):

use this :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
```